# Multiple text fields inside of a Kivy language Button/Label

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I want to have a button that has the Date, then below a weather icon, then below that the temperature. But kivy seems to ignore/overwrite the first text field with the second when i do it this way:

```
Button:
    text: "Day"
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'top'
    padding_y: 10

    text: "temp"
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'bottom'
    padding_y: 30

    Image:
        source: "data/%s.png" % root.dIcon
        pos: self.parent.center_x-(self.width/2), self.parent.center_y-(self.height/4)
        height: self.parent.height-self.parent.height/3
        width: self.parent.width/2
```

Then if i try to build 2 Labels inside of the Button(as below) it wont compile with a *getitem* attribute error.

```
Button:
    Label:
        text: "Day"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'top'
        padding_y: 10
    Label:
        text: "temp"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'bottom'
        padding_y: 30
    Image:
        source: "data/%s.png" % root.dIcon
        pos: self.parent.center_x-(self.width/2), self.parent.center_y-(self.height/4)
        height: self.parent.height-self.parent.height/3
        width: self.parent.width/2
```

Is there a way to do this or do I need to have separate fields with say a BoxLayout where only the image is clickable?

**EDIT:**
I realized that I can achieve this is i put some \n characters between the day and the temp then have the icon lay on top of those. I would still like to see if there is a better way to do this since it will be on different size mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a BoxLayout with a multiline Label

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label: 
        text: "Day\\nTemp"
        halign: 'center'
    Image:
        source: "data/%s.png" % root.dIcon
''')

class MyButton(BoxLayout, Button):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyButton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Or a BoxLayout with 2 Labels:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label: 
        text: "Day"
    Label: 
        text: "Temp"
    Image:
        source: "data/%s.png" % root.dIcon
''')

class MyButton(BoxLayout, Button):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyButton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```